# Llamar al evento de un botón desde un método de otra clase

Tags: vb6

Quisiera saber como llamar al método `btSubmitLogin_Click` desde otra clase.

El usuario se registra en la web y cuando todo está correcto y registrado, automáticamente Inicia Sesión. Eso ocurre cuando se da `click` en el botón `btSubmitLogin` con la función:

```
Private Sub btSubmitLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSubmitLogin.Click
```

Y este es el método al que llama el `btSubmitLogin_Click`:

```
Public Shared Function LoginMetodo(CadenaConexion As String, Usuario As String, Contraseña As String, LabelIntentos As String) As Usuario
```

PD: Además, no sé qué lenguaje es, ya que no me aclaro entre vb, vba, etc... ¿Alguien me lo puede aclarar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenemos 2 casos posibles. Cuándo el bóton está en tu mismo *form* y cuándo está en otro. Entiendo por tu explicación que es el segundo caso pero dejo en la respuesta mi explicación para ambos.

---

Si el botón está definido en la misma clase, es tan sencillo como llamar a la función con argumentos `null`. Ejemplo:

```
btSubmitLogin_Click(null, null);
```

---

Si el botón se encuentra en otra clase tenemos varias opciones:

La primera opción es definir el control del form como `public` y así será accesible des de *cualquier* clase (y por eso **no** lo recomiendo, pero es fácil y rápido), es decir, en lugar de `Private` utiliza `Public`:

```
Public Sub btSubmitLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSubmitLogin.Click
```

Otra manera es utilizando este [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110902/1468942) de SO en inglés:

1. Defines un `EventHandler` en tu primer form:

   ```
   public event EventHandler ButtonFirstFormClicked;
   ```
2. Lo llamas cuándo quieras realizar el `click` que comentas:

   ```
   if (ButtonFirstFormClicked!= null)
        ButtonFirstFormClicked(sender, e);
   ```
3. En el segundo form defines el evento:

   ```
   form1.ButtonFirstFormClicked += (s, e)
   {
        btSubmitLogin_Click(null, null);
   }
   ```

Y el tercer caso (que es el más *bonito*) sería definir una clase padre para ambos forms con la definición del evento y que ambos forms llamen a esa misma función. Es una buena manera de utilizar las herencias y manteniendo la llamada sin que sea pública.

P.D.: El lenguaje es vba

Comment: Muchas gracias creo que me voy a quedar con la segunda opción, ya que la primera como tu dices no es recomendable y la tercera me parece demasiado complicado para mi.

Comment: Realmente no es complicado :) Creas una clase que contenga sólo el `click` que quieres y haces que ambas clases hereden de esta clase (así: `NombreClase : NombreClasePadre`)